# How to import both playbooks and tasks in an Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-lint

I have several playbooks that I sometimes execute individually but I also want to group them in one "master" playbook so that they can all be executed sequentially. I do this using `ansible.builtin.import_playbook`. In this same playbook I also want import a given task. However I am not able to write this in such a way that the ansible linter is happy.

I would expect that something like:

```
---
- name: Master Playbook
  hosts: all

- name: Playbook 1
  ansible.builtin.import_playbook: playbook1.yml

- name: Playbook 2
  ansible.builtin.import_playbook: playbook2.yml

- name: Task 1
  ansible.builtin.import_tasks: task1.yml
```

would work, however I get `'ansible.builtin.import_tasks' is not a valid attribute for a Play`

If for the tasks I instead use:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Task 1
      ansible.builtin.import_tasks: .task1.yml
```

I get `'tasks' is not a valid attribute for a PlaybookInclude`

If I set the `tasks:` line before `- name: Playbook 1` I get instead

```
This task 'ansible.builtin.import_playbook' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules: ansible.windows.win_command, ansible.builtin.import_role, ansible.builtin.meta, include, ansible.builtin.command, ansible.builtin.group_by, ansible.builtin.win_shell, ansible.builtin.set_fact (...)
```

So how can I import both playbooks and tasks in the same playbook?

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find good documentation for this example, and the ones for the `import_playbook` and `import_tasks` aren't very clear. They also don't seem to be present in the Ansible lint documentation.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Regarding the error messages(s) you may have a look into [Ansible Issue #33267 "ERROR! 'include_tasks' is not a valid attribute for a Play"](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/33267#issuecomment-364344947) for some more information.

Comment: Your first play is doing nothing besides gathering facts. Your last play is not valid. I suspect you're looking for this: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/6f9648c93bb1545f01861c4a0611e119